# Object is possible 'null' compiler error even when verifying variable - TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

As you can see in the code snippet below, a certain React element should be shown according to a variable of value type boolean. However, even when checking if the `selectedRepository` is truthy and coercing it to a `Boolean`, the TS compiler gives the error `Object is possibly 'null'`

```
{...}
  const shouldShowRepositoryDetails = !isLoading && Boolean(selectedRepository);

  return (
    <Layout header={<RepositoryDetailsHeader />}>
      {shouldShowRepositoryDetails && (
        <RepositoryDetailsContainer>
          <header>
            <img
              src={selectedRepository.owner?.avatar_url}
              alt={selectedRepository.owner?.login}
              aria-label={selectedRepository.owner?.login}
              title={selectedRepository.owner?.login}
            />

            <div>
              <strong>{selectedRepository.full_name}</strong>
              <p>{selectedRepository.description}</p>
            </div>
          </header>
        </RepositoryDetailsContainer>
      )}
    </Layout>
  );
```

[image: Error Description]

I would like to understand if this is a TS issue or if someone already experienced this.

Comment: Don't put images of your code, paste your code as text with the proper formating.

Comment: Sure! My apologies. I understand that adding directly the code snippet helps in order to test it.

Comment: Why `null` or `false` would be coerced to 0 when printed into the HTML? May you send me a resource or an example of this issue? Also, I've tried with ternary operators and the issue persists.

Comment: Coercion to boolean is not sufficient. You need a [user defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). It isn't enough for it to be truthy, the compiler has to know that it is a type that has the properties you're accessing.

Comment: What happens if you add a more explicit check instead? Like `const shouldShowRepositoryDetails = !isLoading && selectedRepository != null;`?

Comment: @JaredSmith I didn't know about type guards and I'm reading about it now. I've defined a utility function to check the `selectedRepository`, using the following type guard `selectedRepository is Repository`, and now it works 